# Unique pointer to a pointer memory management

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Function `f` allocates a few bytes that are returned in the form of a `unique_ptr<char*>`. How "smart" is this smart pointer ?
When the returned `unique_ptr` goes out of scope, are those allocated bytes returned to the system ?

The managed object here is a pointer (`char*`), not the bytes it points to ! (hence the specialization for arrays)

**Answer** @Miles Budnek

No. Consider a `unique_ptr<char[]>`.

Comment: `new []` should be paired with `delete []`, which'd only be called in `char[]` version

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 "How "smart" is this smart pointer ?" It is not smarter than the user who uses it.

Comment: It doesn't take much to be smarter than a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is a very simple class template.  All it does is store a pointer and `delete` (or `delete[]`, in the case of an array) the object pointed to by that pointer in its destructor.

That is, it looks something like this (slightly simplified):

```
template <typename T>
class unique_ptr
{
private:
    T* ptr_;

public:
    unique_ptr(T* ptr)
      : ptr_{ptr}
    {}

    ~unique_ptr()
    {
        delete ptr_;
    }

    // Other constructors and member functions omitted for brevity
};
```

As you can see, all it does is `delete` the the object directly pointed to by the pointer it holds.  If that object is itself a pointer then any data pointed to by that pointer does not get `delete`d.

---

If you want to return a smart pointer to an allocated array of `char`, then you should create a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` pointing directly to the first `char` in the array.  If you *really* want an extra level of indirection, you would need something like a `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<char[]>>` if you wanted the underlying array to get `delete[]`ed when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.